# Unreliable wireless driver rtl8812au

Tags: wireless

I installed the following github driver for my TP-Link Archer T4UH On 16.04 LTS:
https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Let me be clear that once it starts working, it works reliably at AC speeds until it loses it for whatever reason-  Be it a restart of the computer, logout, or restart of the router.

However, to get it to work, I must disable/enable wireless anywhere from twice to >10 times until it finally sticks.

I don't rightfully know how to troubleshoot this, I can only assume it's a driver problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've found the solution.

The driver doesn't handle dual band networks of the same name too well.  It would sometimes report 144mbps, and sometimes 867mbps link speeds after successfully connecting.

After giving the 5GHz band a different name, it now connects reliably every time.